# 52weeks rolling with running week data

Tags: sql, t-sql

Can someone suggest me how do we consider week to start on Sunday and end on Saturday, while numbering them backwards in a 52 week rolling report like week1, week2.. week52

I want to count my current week as Week1 starting on Sunday, so even if its partial week its still week1 and last week Sunday-Saturday is week2 and so on until 52nd week last year (that would roughly be in September counting backwards). I need this as I am working on a **daily report** that will look for sales for current week and past 51 (full) weeks. My report should also return any week without sales '0' without skipping it.

Comment: sure, use [datepart(week,dateColumn)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql) along with getdate() and some simple math

Comment: That would give me only current week of the year like if I do it for dates between 08/01 and 08/07 it will give me number 31 which is current week of this year, counting back should tell me that is week5 and week before that as week6 etc..

Comment: so... you are using sql server?

Comment: you should use a recursive CTE with datepart to make a list of date ranges and then left join that to your data with a group by.

Comment: if that is to slow then you need to make a dates table with the stuff you need to get the dates without the recursive CTE.

Comment: thanks for the explanation @Sanj. That makes more sense now. Interesting problem you have here!

Comment: @Hogan you were correct in thinking SQL Server, I assume, given the TSQL tag.

Comment: @scsimon - Did you know there are multiple platforms that use TSQL?

Comment: 2 that I knew about, which I'd suspect another tag--but syntax related, I'm not sure as how much difference there would be

Comment: if the report will be run next week, would that week will now be week1?

Comment: @FerdinandGaspar yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way. Note I created the recursive `CTE` to populate some dates. You won't have to do this step, and real only need the `YourWeekOrder = ...` part.

```
declare @startDate date = dateadd(year,-1,getdate()) 
declare @endDate date = getdate()

;with cte as(
    select @startDate as TheDate
    union all
    select dateadd(day,1,TheDate)
    from cte
    where TheDate < @endDate)

select
    TheDate
    ,TheWeekOfYear = datepart(week,TheDate)
    ,YourWeekOrder = dense_rank() over (order by cast(datepart(year,TheDate) as char(4)) + case when len(datepart(week,TheDate)) = 1 then '0' + cast(datepart(week,TheDate) as char(2)) else cast(datepart(week,TheDate) as char(2)) end desc)
from cte 
order by
    TheDate
option(maxrecursion 0)
```

**[SEE IT IN ACTION HERE](http://rextester.com/GMVMH16066)**

Comment: why not just start at 52 in the base of the recursion and then subtract one for on each recursive row?  All this math in the dense_rank() call makes my head spin.  Also you should be adding a week not a day -- I believe the OP wanted the weeks not the days.

Comment: The recursion was for test data only... since this would be off an actual table, the cte would go away @Hogan. And there are 366 rows, not 53

Comment: I don't think it would be off an actual table.  The actual table might have weeks with no data -- you have to generate it like this and left join or you lose those weeks.  Yes that is why the CTE should be by week not by day so it is 52 rows for each week.

Comment: Well, even if it wasn't off an actual table, the OP talked about partial weeks. So a partial week would suggest this would be day-by-day, hence the calendar table and my method. If it was simply weeks, then the solution would be far less complicated.

Comment: @scsimon thank you very much, this was what I was looking for exactly, I see what I need now.

Comment: @Hogan it looks like you were right about the table but not the row count. Good working with you as always man.